# How to Parse Json Object and use its variables in scala

Tags: json, scala, http, servlets

How do I get the values of access Token if the Json String returned is this:

```
var result = Http("https://example.com").postForm(Seq("clientId" -> clientId, "clientSecret" -> clientSecret)).asString

var jsonObj = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(result.
accessToken = jsonObj.get("accessToken")
```

The Result of the request to example.com is:

```
{
    "accessToken": "xxyyyzzz",
    "expiresIn": 3600
}
```

Comment: Are you having some problem... I think this code should be working fine... considering that you change last line because `scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull( result )` returns `Option[ Any ]`

Comment: Im getting the compilation error: Any does not take parameters

Answer (score 3):

Basically, `scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull` returns `Option[ Any ]`.

`Any` because the return type depends on the structure of the JSON input.

`Option` because your JSON string can be erroneous and hence `None` in case of error and `Some[ Any ]` in case of success.

So... In this case your JSON is,

```
{
    "accessToken": "xxyyyzzz",
    "expiresIn": 3600
}
```

Which is clearly a Map - type thing. So... In this case the return type will be an instance of `Option[ Map[ String, Any] ]` but will be refereed to by a variable of type `Option[ Any ]`.

So... What you have to do is following,

```
val optionAny = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull( result )

val accessToken = optionAny match {
    case None => ""
    case Some( mapAsAny ) => mapAsAny match {
        case m: Map[ String, Any ] => {
            // Map[ A, B].get( key: A ) returns Option[ B ]
            // So here m.get( "accessToken" ) Will return Option[ Any ]
            val optionToken = m.get( "accessToken" )
            optionToken match {
                case None =>  ""
                case Some( strAsAny ) => strAsAny match {
                    case str: String => str
                    case _ => ""
                }
            }
        }
        case _ => ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now getting the error: "missing parameter type for expanded function
[error] The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
[error] Expected type was: ?
[error]       case Some( mapAsAny) => {"

Comment: Ohh... I did a mistake in the code. Fixed it now. Change this - `case Some( mapAsAny ) => {` to `case Some( mapAsAny ) => mapAsAny match {`.

Comment: While this is an excellent answer if you control the server code then you should consider using something like Argonaut which looks at your Scala case classes and automatically converts both to and from json. See this answer where it seamlessly deals with structured json/objects using just two lines of code to ask it to create the mapping http://stackoverflow.com/a/18675897/329496

Comment: Though Argonaut is great... I will recommend other libraries more ( just becasue of better documentation and tutorials ) such as - Gson, Jackson or PlayJson.